# How do you load attribute data from the entity into a single (1) UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, load-data-infile

I'm new to coding with Swift, and I've been using the tutorial from Udemy by Aaron  Caines, which has been great.  The tutorial he did was using a UITableViewController.

I have an app that uses a single UIViewController (ONLY ONE VIEW and it's not a UITableViewController).  I've already loaded CoreData into the build phases.  I've been able to verify that the data is saved in the attributes, but for some reason, I can't load the data back into the two text boxes and one image view that I have in the view controller.

I've placed a couple of questions as comments within the code.

It should be as easy as setting up the variables:

```
@IBOutlet var textName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var descriptionName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
```

calling the entity and getting the persistent container ready to load and receive data:

```
let pc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

fetching the data

```
var frc : NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>()

    func  fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "NamedEntity")

        // DO I NEED A SORTER IF I'M NOT USING A TABLEVIEW?

        //let sorter = NSSortDescriptor(key: "accounttext", ascending: false)
        //fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sorter]

        return fetchRequest

    }


    func getFRC() -> NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> {

        frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: pc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        //OCCASIONALLY THERE'S AN ISSUE WITH THE sectionNameKeyPath. 
        //THE ERROR INVOLVES TRYING TO "UNWRAP A NIL VALUE". 
        //IS THERE ANOTHER VALUE I SHOULD BE CONSIDERING?

        return frc

    }
```

fetching the data whenever the view loads or appears:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        frc = getFRC()
        frc.delegate = self

        do {

            try frc.performFetch()

        }

        catch {

            print(error)
            return

        }

        //  WHAT DO I USE HERE IF I'M NOT USING A TABLEVIEW?

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        frc = getFRC()
        frc.delegate = self

        do {

            try frc.performFetch()

        }

        catch {

            print(error)
            return

        }

        //  WHAT DO I USE HERE IF I'M NOT USING A TABLEVIEW?

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

and then loading it into the appropriate boxes:

```
 //THIS IS WHERE THINGS GET STUCK
 // HOW DO I CALL THE ATTRIBUTES OF MY ENTITY AND UPDATE MY VARIABLES IF I'M NOT USING A TABLEVIEW?

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! cellAccountTableViewCell 

        let item = frc.object(at: indexPath) as! Entity

        cell.nameText.text = item.accounttext  

        cell.descriptionText.text = item.amounttext 

        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data: (item.image)! as Data) 

        return cell
    }
```

I only have 2 text boxes and 1 image view.  I've spent the last three days scouring dozens of useless forum topics and countless youtube videos for this answer, but it seems that everyone gives a tutorial on using a table view controller.

The most *useful* thing I've found was a video by Electronic Armory.  This helped me understand the structure of the Entity(ies), attrubutes, and the persistentContainer. It also deals with the relational aspect the database.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=da6W7wDh0Dw

Can I use core data on ONE (1) single UIViewController, and if so, how do I call the data and load it into the appropriate fields? Let me know if there's any more info needed.

I'm really trying to understand the Core Data process. What am I missing, or what am I not understanding about the loading process?  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Luke

Answer (score 0):

> I have an app that uses a single UIViewController (ONLY ONE VIEW and it's not a UITableViewController).
>
> I only have 2 text boxes and 1 image view.

Assuming there's only one entity returned from the fetch (otherwise how are you going to show them all?), probably something like this:

```
//  WHAT DO I USE HERE IF I'M NOT USING A TABLEVIEW?

//self.tableView.reloadData()

if let fetchResult = frc.fetchedObjects{
    if let item = fetchResult.first as? Entity{
         textName.text = item.accounttext
         descriptionName.text = item.amounttext   
         imageView.image = UIImage(data: (item.image)! as Data)   
     }

}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll play with this and let you know what I find.